# Ambiguous Python reference count of an object as a class constructor's argument

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider the following Python code snippet (produces the same result on both Python 2 and 3):

```py
import sys
REF = sys.getrefcount

class Foo(object):
    pass

def function(foo):
    print( REF(foo) )

class Class(object):
    def __init__(self, foo):
        print( REF(foo) )

print( REF(Foo()) ) # output: 1, ok
function(Foo()) # output: 3, ok
Class(Foo()) # output: 4, what ???
```

Having been searching Google so far, every site I've reached only gives the following cases in which reference count of an object increments by one:

- assignment operator
- argument passing
- appending an object to a list (object's reference count will be increased).

(https://rushter.com/blog/python-garbage-collector/ as a concrete source)

If I understand right, in the call `function(Foo())`, each of the following step does increment the reference to Foo() (an object initialized on the fly) by 1:

- Foo() is passed to `function` as an argument => +1 ref
- It is assigned to variable `foo` inside `function` => +1 ref
- It is passed to `sys.getrefcount` as an argument => +1 ref
  Thus 3 references, as expected.

If so, how can the last line claims that reference count of the object is 4 ? The code calls the constructor of a class, which is also a function, so the reference count to `Foo()` should be 3 as well !

So is there any mystery of Python refcount here ? Are there any extra cases in which refcount also increments ?

**BACKGROUND**: I want to detect whether the object passed to the function/constructor is initialized *on the fly*, i.e. out of the caller's control, so I can do some sort of memory saving: reuse an existing object without making use of a new one.

Comment: "I want to detect whether the object passed to the function/constructor is initialized on the fly, i.e. out of the caller's control, so I can do some sort of memory saving: reuse an existing object without making use of a new one." This doesn't seem like something you can accomplish reasonably.

Comment: Anyway, `Class(Foo())` the object is being referenced in `type.__call__`, probably in `Foo.__new__` and `Foo.__init__`, although, probably only one of those references exists by the time you get to `REF(foo)` in `Foo.__init__`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga ok thank u for the clue of `type.__call__`, maybe that's the correct answer. Btw I've decided to take another approach that makes more sense in my original code.